# AngularJS - how to use ng-repeat in different containers

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, angularjs

I am trying to use ng-repeat to display the array of numbers.  How to achieve this if I want it to be in different containers, for example in different `ul`?  Also, each `ul` can only contain at most 2 `li`.

```
$scope.numbers = [1,2,3,4,5]

<div ng-controller="myController">
    <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>5</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I would convert your array in controller to [[1,2], [3,4], [5]] and than use nested ng-repeat to iterate: `<ul ng-repeat="pair in array"><li ng-repeat="number in pair">{{number}}</li></ul>`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should split that `numbers` array into chunks, then use a nested `ng-repeat`.

**JavaScript:**

```js
var i, l = $scope.numbers.length;

$scope.chunks = [];

for ( i = 0; i < l; i += 2) {
    $scope.chunks.push( $scope.numbers.slice(i, i + 2) );
}
```

**HTML:**

```html
<div ng-controller="myController">
    <ul ng-repeat="chunk in chunks">
        <li ng-repeat="number in chunk">{{ number }}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

---

[**See it here in action**](http://plnkr.co/edit/ck4rBXGJ6mbuBG6Zr0Ju?p=preview).

Comment: What about when you're using dynamically sized chunks? I have this problem as I'm using viewports to decide how many columns there are...

Comment: @mkornblum - Then you just create one big `ul`, and give the `li`s a percentage width according to the media query.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing, but I was initially trying to fill the left hand column to screen height before moving on to the next one to the right. I couldn't figure out a way of doing that...